# Linear Equations II

Tags: linear-algebra

I was downloading spending time to download 24 files, and I wanted to know somewhat how long it would be. I know linear equations isn't ideal for non-linear things, but I thought I'd try. I was using $y-y_1=m(x-x_1)$

Time elapse (in minutes) versus files remaining (in files)
0:24
64:20
75:19
142:15
150:14
222:10
257:7

I took (64 minutes - 0 minutes) / (20 files - 24 files) for the slope and got -16

$y-y_1 = -16(x-x_1)$
reforming I got $y=-16(x-x_1) + y_1$

taking the first pair (0,24) for $x_1$ and $y_1$ I get:
$y=-16(x-0) + 24$

which reduces to:
y=-16x + 24

For 222 minutes in I get -3528, where my actual result was 10 files remaining. Where did I go wrong?

Comment: Looks like you've swapped $x$ and $y$. In the slope computation, you're using $y$ to represent minutes, but you are using it for files when you plug into the equation.

Answer (score 0):

You have an over-determined system: multiple data points to which you are trying to fit a line. If this is not perfectly linear, you will have issues fitting things perfectly.

Typically, in such problems, we find a line that minimizes the squared error. To do so, we can construct a *Vandermonde matrix* of the form:

$$A = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & x_1 \\ 1 & x_2 \\ 1 & x_3 \\\vdots & \vdots \\ 1 & x_n\end{pmatrix}$$

Then, we wish to find parameters $m$ and $b$ such that $r = A\begin{pmatrix} b \\ m\end{pmatrix}-y$ is minimized. To do so, simply solve $A^TA\begin{pmatrix} b \\ m\end{pmatrix} = A^Ty$, recognizing that $A^TA$ is a symmetric $2\times 2$ matrix.

Answer (score 0):

It appears you have misordered your data. You want the rise over the run for slope over those two points. If I am reading this correctly you have run over rise. If you want to make a line using those first two points,

$$m=\frac{20-24}{64-0}=-\frac{1}{16}.$$

Now your equation is
$$y-y_1=m(x-x_1) \Rightarrow y-24=-\frac{1}{16}(x-0) \Rightarrow y=-\frac{1}{16}x+24.$$
Here is a plot of your points and the line you were attempting:

[image]